# Preview does not render code blocks as code if they contain a paragraph separator (unicode decimal 8233, hex 2029)

Tags: bug, code-formatting, editor, markdown-rendering

If you edit this question, you'll see the problem.

Here's a code block with a [paragraph separator](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8233) char between "foo" and "bar":

```
var str = "foo bar"
var also = "other lines"
```

The above line renders in the preview as if it's not code (ie not indented), however it renders OK when saved.

Although this is pretty minor, it's still a bug.

[image: See screen shot]

Comment: I can't edit the question. Can someone please include a screenshot?

Comment: @Justlearnedit link to screen shot added (best I could do from my phone)

Comment: "however it renders OK when saved. " Arguable since it doesn't show anything between foo and bar. Maybe it should display as `foo?bar` which is what notepad++ displays ...

Comment: @DavidPostill We don't control what browsers or operating systems do with unknown or invisible characters, and that's not our responsibility. That's a system font issue. It displays a weird bordered box for me in Chrome on Windows.